# Setting attributes of custom views in Android

Tags: android, xml, view

I've got a class that extends a button. I want to add an additional attribute to it. Is there any way to initialize that attribute from XML? For example:

```
<MyButton android:id="@+id/myBtn" myValue="Hello World"></MyButton>
```

---

```
public class MyButton extends Button{
private String myValue = "";

public CalcButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can have custom attributes and assign values to it in XML. You can even assign methods to handle custom events on your widgets. [Long press definition at XML layout, like android:onClick does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706038/long-press-definition-at-xml-layout-like-androidonclick-does/13417824#13417824)

The needed steps.

1. Implement your custom widget.
2. Then add file attrs.xml in *res/values/* with following content:

   ```
   <xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <declare-styleable name="MyButton">
           <attr name="myValue" format="string"/>
       </declare-styleable>
   </resources>
   ```
3. Retrieve values from XML in MyButton constructor. Remember to implement all constructors, not only one.
4. Use new attribute in your layout xml:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/**your.package**"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       >

       <your.package.MyButton
           android:id="@+id/theId"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           custom:myValue="myDoSomething"
       />
       <!-- Other stuff -->
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: how do you actually fetch custom:myValue within the MyButton class?

Comment: @GeniaS. please look at the link I have provided. There is a full code example with retreiving valuse from xml in constructor.