# Android: How to get a custom attribute of an XML in Activity class

Tags: android, xml

How do I get the attribute value "required" in my Activity Class?

**1. values\attrs.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="EditText"> 
    <attr name="required" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**2. layout\text.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mycompany.test"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtTest"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:inputType="text" 
        custom:required="true" />
```

Comment: Do you find an answer ? I'm struggling with the same question :)

Answer (score 2):

In EditText **constructor** add logic to read data from xml:

```
    public EditText(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) 
    {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.EditText);

      final int N = a.getIndexCount();
      for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      {
        int attr = a.getIndex(i);
        switch (attr)
        {
            case R.styleable.EditText_required: {
                if (context.isRestricted()) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("The "+getClass().getCanonicalName()+":required attribute cannot "
                            + "be used within a restricted context");
                }

                boolean defaultValue = false;
                final boolean required = a.getBoolean(attr, defaultValue );
                //DO SOMETHING
                break;
            }
            default: 
                break;
        }
      }
      a.recycle();
    }
```

The *switch* construct was used to check for many custom attributes. If you are only interested in one attribute you can skip *switch statement*

If you want to learn more, especially how to add method handler using xml attribute read this:
[Long press definition at XML layout, like android:onClick does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706038/long-press-definition-at-xml-layout-like-androidonclick-does/13417824#13417824)