# Receive a long press/click on a linear layout in android?

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android-linearlayout, onlongclicklistener, long-click

I'm painfully new to android and I've run into a wall.

I'm trying get a linear layout to function more like a button, with different actions for press and long press - The reason being so I can have 2 differently formatted text labels on each "button". Something along the lines of:

```
-------------------------
|          2nd          |  <- Label for long press (regular/smaller type)
|           =           |  <- Label for regular press (bold/larger type)
-------------------------
```

The posts I've found explain how to receive a regular click on a linear layout (I use the onClick attribute in the layout XML). But I've had no luck with long press. I've tried to define a new onLongClick attribute for xml as described in Aleksander Gralak's answer here: [Long press definition at XML layout, like android:onClick does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706038/long-press-definition-at-xml-layout-like-androidonclick-does) . But had no such luck - it looks like it was intended for a text view, I tried changing it to linear layout but failed miserably.

Here is the object in question: `Main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/darkgrey_button"
    android:onClick="equals" android:longClickable="true" android:id="equalsbutton"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2nd"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" = "
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And `Main.java`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void equals(View view) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Add an `id` to your layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_button_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    … >
```

In your `Main.java`

Get a reference to your `LinearLayout` and set a `OnLongClickListener`.

```
LinearLayout buttonLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_button_layout);
…
buttonLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Long click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
    }

});
```

Comment: The general idea here worked for me.  I was able to set the listener on a WebView object