# Is there an android:onLongClick equivalent of android:onClick?

Tags: android

I like the convenience of `android:onClick`, which allows you to set up a click listener on a view simply by assigning a pre-defined style including:

```
<item name="android:onClick">myOnClickFunction</item>
```

If you also assign a unique `android:tag` to each view, then in `myOnClickFunction()` you can check the `tag` and customise the click functionality accordingly (or just do the same for each view).

My question is: is there an equivalent *long* click property (certainly 'android:onLongClick' doesn't exist), or is it a case of assigning a long click listener to each view separately via `setOnLongClickListener()`?

Comment: it's the latter.

Comment: In this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706038/long-press-definition-at-xml-layout-like-androidonclick-does read answer given by "Aleksander Gralak" it will give idea to you

Comment: Why on earth don't they just add a native `android:onLongClick`?  They obviously thought it a good idea to add `android:onClick` so why not `android:onLongClick` at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I woud suggest you to take a look at [data binding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#EventHandling).

> This document explains how to use the Data Binding Library to write declarative layouts and minimize the glue code necessary to bind your application logic and layouts.

Comment: Looks interesting but wouldn't really know where to start :-(

Comment: :-) I did, but I think I could understand it just as well if it had been written in Greek.  I think I work better by seeing a simple example, like how this could be applied to a very simple case where you want to add a long click listener to a `TextView` via XML